# Number of possible extensions of field into algebraically closed field

Tags: field-theory

[image]

I have understood completely the reasoning above Proposition 2.7.
 But I cannot understand how to prove the proposition itself. Let me ask my questions more precisely?

1) In the reasoning above $\beta$ is a root of $p^{\sigma}$  not a root of $p$.  And this confuses me.

2) Why the number of possible extensions is $\leq$ number of roots of $p$? Why it cannot be bigger?

3) How to show that distinct roots give different extensions?

Unfortunately, I cannot to prove this statment in rigorous way and I would be very grateful if anyone can show its proof. I would like to see detailed proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In the reasoning $\beta$ is a root of $p^{\sigma}$. Nothing at all is said about whether it is a root of $p$ or not; that is immaterial. (It *could* be a root of $p^{\sigma}$ as well, e.g., if $\sigma$ is the identity).
2. $p^{\sigma}$ has the same number of roots (and of distinct roots) as $p$ in $L$. Since the image of $\alpha$ must be a root of $p^{\sigma}$, and completely determines the extension, the number of *potential* images of $\alpha$ is at most the number of distinct roots of $p^{\sigma}$, which is the same as the number of distinct roots of $p$.
3. Because if $\beta\neq\beta’$, then the image of $\alpha$ under one extension is $\beta$ and under the other extension is $\beta’$. Given that the two extensions send $\alpha$ to different things, the two extensions are different.

Comment: Thanks for reply but let me ask you question regarding second part. Why image of $\alpha$ completely determines extension? This is what i cannot comprehend.

Comment: @ZFR: Because you are trying to extend $\sigma$ from $k$ to $k(\alpha)=k[\alpha]$. If you know what happens to $\alpha$, since you already know what happens to $k$, you then know what happens to everything. Remember: $\sigma$ is a field automorphism. If every element is a polynomial in $\alpha$ with coefficients in $k$, you know what happens to the coefficients, and you know what happens to $\alpha$, thenyou know what happens to the element.

Comment: Brilliant answer. Finally I've understood the proposition on which I've spent 3 days. Let me ask you one more questions: 1) Could I say that number of possible extensions is $\leq$ $\deg p(X)$?

Comment: @ZFR: since the number of distinct roots is less than or equal to the total number of roots (counting multiplicity), which in turn is less than or equal to the degree of the polynomial, yes, you can. But then you would be saying less than what the theorem states.

Comment: I don't understand you last sentence "But then you would be saying less than what the theorem states."

Comment: @ZFR: “degree of $p$” is a potentially larger upper bound than “number of roots of $p$”, which in turn is a potentially larger upper bound than “number of distinct roots of $p$”. The theorem tells you the number of extensions is at most the number of distinct roots of $p$. If instead of saying that you say “the number of extensions is at most the degree of $p$”, then you are giving a *worse* upper bound, so you are saying less. I mean, you could *also* say that the number of possible extensions is *finite* (also true), but surely you see that this is less precise information?